# Deleting a member from a struct gives error in c++

Tags: c++, struct

In my code I have a struct declared like this .

```
int IN_USE=5;

struct ReadyQueue
{

    int size;

    struct process * Active; // Pointer to another struct 

    struct process readyProcesses[IN_USE]; // contains 5 elements of struct 
                                              process
}ready;
```

In the middle of my code I am doing 
delete &ready.readyProcesses[2];

I get the following error during run time

"pointer being freed was not allocated"

I am a bit stuck , how to overcome this problem . It is necessary to remove that struct  element from the array . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you ever allocate memory for the struct using `new`? You need to do that before you can `delete` it.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile. And you can only `delete` objects you created with `new`

Comment: *how to overcome this problem* -- Learn to use `std::vector<>`?

Comment: I didn't use new ,The code had compiled . any example of new ?

Comment: *I didn't use new ,The code had compiled* -- Code compiling only means there are no syntax errors.  It doesn't mean the program will run successfully.

Comment: Look at a simple c++ tutorial on the **stack** and the **heap**.

Comment: If this code compiled then you're not using a C++ compiler. array fields in structs absolutely need to have their size known at the compile time

Comment: Also, you can't remove items from an array.  An array cannot be resized.  So you need to clarify exactly what you mean by "remove".  Also, the code is not valid C++, as stated earlier, an array in C++ must use a compile-time expression to denote the number of items.  If you really and truly want to remove an item from a contiguous "array" of items, then you want `std::vector` and use the `std::vector::erase` function.

Comment: If you want to be able to delete the array then make readyProcesses a pointer like you do with Active and then new the array and point readyProcesses to the created memory.

Comment: Alright i will first convert it to pointer and try , thanks guys for the suggestion , will tell you the outcome .

Comment: @JerryJeremiah  struct process *readyProcesses=new struct process[IN_USE];

Comment: Soomething like that ?

Comment: Don't forget to use delete[] if you new an array.  Maybe I should write an answer.

Comment: Again ran into same problem after using struct process *readyProcesses=new struct process[IN_USE];

Comment: Hi Delete[] works , thanks for the suggestion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only `delete` something that you use `new` to create.  In your case `struct process readyProcesses[IN_USE]` is a hardcoded array and is not dynamically created so you can't delete it.  What you need is an array that is dynamically created - that means readyProcesses must be a pointer to an array.

Finally: when you new a single object you use `delete` but when you new an array of objects you need to use `delete[]` instead.

Here is an example of both:

```
const int IN_USE=5;

struct process
{
    /*...*/
};

struct ReadyQueue
{
    int size;
    struct process * Active; // Pointer to another struct 
    struct process * readyProcesses; // contains 5 elements of struct 
} ready;

int main()
{
    ready.Active = new struct process; // just one object
    ready.readyProcesses = new struct process[IN_USE]; // a whole array

    // now do something with ready

    delete[] ready.readyProcesses; // delete the array
    delete ready.Active; // delete the single object

    return 0;
}
```

If you did want to be able to delete individual array elements instead of deleting the whole array you could do the following instead but this leaves the index not pointing to anything.  If you wanted to delete the entire index along with what it is pointing to (which would make the array smaller) then you should be using std::vector instead.

```
const int IN_USE=5;

struct process
{
    /*...*/
};

struct ReadyQueue
{
    int size;
    struct process * Active; // Pointer to another struct 
    struct process * readyProcesses[IN_USE]; // Array of pointers
} ready;

int main()
{
    ready.Active = new struct process; // just one object

    // Allocate one object for each index in the array
    for(int i=0;i<IN_USE;i++)
        ready.readyProcesses[i] = new struct process;

    // now do something with ready

    if(IN_USE>2) // if there at least three items
    {
        delete ready.readyProcesses[2]; // delete the third item
        ready.readyProcesses[2] = nullptr; // mark it as not pointing to anything
    }

    // now do more stuff with ready

    // Now delete each single object in the array
    // item 2 is nullptr so delete won't do anything with that
    for(int i=0;i<IN_USE;i++)
        delete ready.readyProcesses[i];

    delete ready.Active; // delete the single object

    return 0;
}
```

If you do delete an item in the middle of the program you need to set that spot to nullptr so that when you delete every index in the array at the end you won't try to delete something that has already been deleted.

If you really want to dynamically allocate everything you could:

```
const int IN_USE=5;

struct process
{
    /*...*/
};

struct ReadyQueue
{
    int size;
    struct process * Active; // Pointer to another struct 
    struct process ** readyProcesses; // Pointer to array of pointers
} ready;

int main()
{
    ready.Active = new struct process; // just one object
    ready.readyProcesses = new struct process * [IN_USE]; // an array of pointers

    // Allocate one object for each index in the array
    for(int i=0;i<IN_USE;i++)
        ready.readyProcesses[i] = new struct process;

    // now do something with ready

    // Now delete each single object in the array
    for(int i=0;i<IN_USE;i++)
        delete ready.readyProcesses[i];

    delete[] ready.readyProcesses; // delete the (now empty) array
    delete ready.Active; // delete the single object

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi , in your example you are deleting the whole of array , again when i try to delete an individual element in an array , i get th same problem

Comment: So you want an array of individually allocated processes so that you can delete them individually?  That will leave holes of unallocated slots in the array.  Are you sure you want an array?  I'll update the answer but I don't think you are asking the right questions.  Maybe you should explain what you are trying to accomplish so we can figure out the right data structure to use.

Comment: Hi Jerry , My requirement is that , 5 elements will be stored in the struct array , based on some condition I have to delete  an element from the array. It can be the first or second or the last element .

Comment: If it is always an array of 5 items you probably want the second example...

Comment: Hi , one more thing here , the deletion of one random element isn't working , let me check again

Comment: Hi I clearly understood now , I have a question , can we use free as well ?

Comment: a question here ready.readyProcesses[2] = nullptr; can we add a new value to that location ? if yes how to do that

Comment: Instead of assigning `nullptr` or sometime later after assigning it just assign `new struct process` which allocates a new one.